# NSMutableArray is nil. Why?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

After I add objects to my `NSMutableArray` it becomes `nil` (I check it in `NSLog`)

---

**Code**

```
guests = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
guests = [localDictionary objectForKey:@"guestsArray"];

[guests addObject:@"1"];
[guests addObject:@"12"];
[guests addObject:@"31"];

if(guests == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"WHY?");
}
```

Do you have any ideas why its happening ? What should I check ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because `[localDictionary objectForKey:@"guestsArray"]` is nil.

Comment: But I add objects after, doesn't it make it "not nil" ? :)

Comment: No, because you are adding them to an object that is nil. It's like it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks ! Now I understand.
Last question: is it possible to make "guestArray" not nil somehow ?
Because I created this key for user's data and it can't be filled with something at the first launch.

Comment: You can do something like this: `if([localDictionary objectForKey:@"guestsArray"] == nil) [localDictionary setObject:[NSMutableArray array] forKey:@"guestsArray"];`

Comment: Now it shows this:
`[_NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'`
Where I made a mistake again ?

Comment: Your `localDictionary` must be `NSMutableDictionary`, not `NSDictionary`.

Comment: Its NSMutableDictionary.

`localDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 
localDictionary = [mainArray objectAtIndex:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"currentIndex"]];`

Comment: Again, it's because `[mainArray objectAtIndex:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"currentIndex"]];` is NSDictionary, not NSMutableDictionary. Try `localDictionary = [[mainArray objectAtIndex:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"currentIndex"]] mutableCopy];`

Answer (score 3):

You create a NSMutableArray in your first line and then you reassign the variable with an object taken from a dictionary.

If you want add objects from the object in localDictionary with guestsArray key, use this instead :

```
guests = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[localDictionary objectForKey:@"guestsArray"]];
```

With that, even if your "guestsArray object" doesn't exist in localDictionary, your guests array will not be nil.